# How to access variables from one method into another method in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and creating a calculator program using methods. I am having trouble accessing variables num1, op, and num2 from method requeset_op_num into method answer. 
I keep getting an error saying undefined local variable or method `request_op_num' for main:Object (NameError)

```
#this method will ask the user for numbers and operator
def request_op_num
    puts "Please enter your first number"
    num_1 = gets.to_f
    puts "Please enter the operator you would like to use (+,-,*,/)"
    op = gets
    puts "Please enter your second number"
    num_2 = gets.to_f
end
request_op_num

#this method will compare the operators and spit out the answer
def answer
    if op == '+'
        puts num_1 + num_2
    elsif op == '-'
        puts num_1 - num_2
    elsif op == '*'
        puts num_1 * num_2
    elsif op == '/'
        puts num_1 / num_2
    else
        puts "wrong operator"
    end
end

answer
```

Comment: Not relevant to your current question, but don't forget `gets` will include the newline character (because it reads an entire line). So `op == '+'` will for example never be true, since `op` is `"+\n"`. You can remove the last trailing `"\n"` character with [`String#chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/String.html#method-i-chomp).

Comment: thanks, i didn't realize that was an issue as well. I fixed that up as you mentioned and it worked along with the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables are scoped to the local context. You cannot access them from arbitrary other places in the code; that's the whole point of them being *local*.

If you want to access a variable globally across the whole program (which is, 99.9% of the time, very bad practice), then you need to declare it as a global variable.

In ruby, global variables are declared by naming them with a `$` symbol, e.g. `$num_1`.

---

Alternatively, you could **pass the variables** into the other method. For example:

```
def request_op_num
  puts "Please enter your first number"
  num_1 = gets.to_f
  puts "Please enter the operator you would like to use (+,-,*,/)"
  op = gets
  puts "Please enter your second number"
  num_2 = gets.to_f

  answer(num_1, num_2, op)
end

def answer(num_1, num_2, op)
  if op == '+'
    puts num_1 + num_2
  elsif op == '-'
    puts num_1 - num_2
  elsif op == '*'
    puts num_1 * num_2
  elsif op == '/'
    puts num_1 / num_2
  else
    puts "wrong operator"
  end
end

request_op_num
```

Or:

```
def request_op_num
  puts "Please enter your first number"
  num_1 = gets.to_f
  puts "Please enter the operator you would like to use (+,-,*,/)"
  op = gets
  puts "Please enter your second number"
  num_2 = gets.to_f

  [num_1, num_2, op]
end

def answer(num_1, num_2, op)
  if op == '+'
    puts num_1 + num_2
  elsif op == '-'
    puts num_1 - num_2
  elsif op == '*'
    puts num_1 * num_2
  elsif op == '/'
    puts num_1 / num_2
  else
    puts "wrong operator"
  end
end

num_1, num_2, op = request_op_num

answer(num_1, num_2, op)
```

Comment: thank you, worked out perfectly, went with the second example and that worked along with fixing the ```op = gets.chomp```